# Render a DataGrid cell with a colored oval with text/icon in it

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

I need your help related to mui/x-data-grid. I am trying to render a cell in mui/x-data-grid with text/icon in it based on the text value, but unable to do so.
The following is the codesandbox link:
[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-shamir-4pgtr?file=/src/App.js)

And I want something similar to [this](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/#commercial-version).

[image: Sample desired output]

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`Chip`](https://mui.com/components/chips/) component in MUI instead of rolling out your own, to make it look like in the screenshot, set its `variant` to `outlined`. Below is an example:

```
function getChipProps(params: GridRenderCellParams): ChipProps {
  if (params.value === "RED") {
    return {
      icon: <WarningIcon style={{ fill: red[500] }} />,
      label: params.value,
      style: {
        borderColor: red[500]
      }
    };
  } else {
    return {
      icon: <CheckCircleIcon style={{ fill: blue[500] }} />,
      label: params.value,
      style: {
        borderColor: blue[500]
      }
    };
  }
}


const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  {...},
  {
    field: "status",
    headerName: "Status",
    renderCell: (params) => {
      return <Chip variant="outlined" {...getChipProps(params)} />;
    }
  }
];
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Your solution is what I exactly needed. You made my day. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

```
MUI column data grid example : 

{
              field: "",
              width:150,
              renderCell: (cellValues) => {
                return (
                  <>
                    <IconButton
                      color="secondary"
                      aria-label="add an alarm"
                      onClick={(event) =>
                        this.handleModalDelete(event, cellValues)
                      }
                    >
                      <DeleteIcon style={{ color: blue[500] }} />
                    </IconButton>
                  </>
                );
              },
            }
```